# How to update github source on digital ocean app platform?

Tags: digital-ocean

I have an app deployed on digital ocean and would like to update the source (github) where it is deployed from. I moved my github repo to an organization and now digital ocean does not seem to able to access it anymore.

[image]

I believe that all the rights are configured correctly on github. I can only edit the chosen branch for the existing repo, cant change the gh repo. Do i have to create a new app and configure everything again?

Comment: see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-change-github-repo-name

Answer (score 5):

You can easily download the yaml-file from the app's control panel, edit in your preferred text editor and upload the new file.